# Xml to XSLT: getting attributes value and so on

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface id="RESTInterface">
          .....     
            <abstract_method name="authenticateUser">
                <access>public</access>
                <parameters>
        <argument type="String">account</argument>
        <argument type="String">password</argument> 
                </parameters>
                <throws>
                    <exception>RemoteException</exception>
                    <exception>SecurityException</exception>
                </throws>
                <return>boolean</return>
            </abstract_method>
            <abstract_method name="verifyUser">
                <access>public</access>
                <parameters>
                    <argument type="aURL">link</argument>
                </parameters>
                <return>void</return>
            </abstract_method>
</interface>
```

And I am trying to create an xslt style sheet to create this result:

[image: results]

Comment: You're expected to show an attempt and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with smth like this. (I made the assumption that you might be restricted to XSLT 1.0)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="_http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="interface"></xsl:apply-templates>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="interface">
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Operation</td>
                    <td>Argument(s)</td>
                    <td>Return</td>
                    <td>Exception</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="abstract_method"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="abstract_method">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
            <td><p><xsl:apply-templates select="./parameters/argument"></xsl:apply-templates></p></td>
            <td><p><xsl:value-of select="./return/text()"/></p></td>
            <td><p><xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="count(./throws/exception) &gt; 0">Yes</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>No</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose></p></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="argument">
        <span><xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>: <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::argument">, </xsl:if></span>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```